# Difference between the specification and the xsd of WS-Trust 1.3

Tags: xml, web-services, validation, xsd, ws-trust

I realized that there is a difference between what the WS-Trust 1.4 specification says and the xsd that validates it.

The namespace that declares the specification is: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512

But the namespace on the xsd is: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/

And when I try to validate an xml formed with the WS-Trust specification it gives me an error.

I am correct in saying that the xsd should read http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512 and not http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ ?

Reference:

- docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust-1.3-os.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you found the schema you talk about, but the one I found is at

http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/v1.4/ws-trust-1.4.xsd

and its targetNamespace has no trailing "/".

Comment: The reference is: docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust-1.3-os.html

Comment: The only link to a schema I can find on that page is to http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/ws-trust.xsd, which doesn't appear to exist.